# Dojo update only part of template

Tags: dojo

I have created a widget based template like,

```
<div class="content">
    <div>
        <!-- rest of content-->
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="panel" data-dojo-attach-point="sysinfo">
                <ul class="col-md-12 stats">
                    <li class="stat col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">Host:</br> <span><b class="value">{{hname}}</b></span>
                    </li>
                    <li class="stat col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6"># CPU:</br> <span><b class="value">{{cpu}}</b></span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

How do I update only content of sysinfo ?

Till now I was doing,

```
var widget =  this;
widget.template = new dtl.Template(widget.templateString);
var template = widget.template;
template.update(node, stats); // but it update complete content as node == content. I just want to refresh sysinfo.
```

I also tried,

```
template.update(this.sysinfo, stats); // but it throws exceptions
```

Any ideas?

Comment: within your widget code you need to set a setter function see [here](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.9/recipes/custom_widget/) for details and then use the setter function for updating the sysinfo content. The sysinfo will be available as a variable in your widge code. In your setter function you can then use something like this e.g  `_setSysinfo:function (argument) { sysinfo.innerHtml = argument }`. The setter function will be called e.g `widget.Sysinfo(stats);`

Comment: @frank cant we do `template.update(node, context)`

Comment: The template will be available only after it is parsed by the parser. The template is converted to DOM nodes by the parser. There is no such method as update for updating the template. The attach point attribute allows you to specify the name of the variable that the parser will create at the time of creation of the widget, which is available for manupilation. Did you have a look at the link that was provided in the previous comment?

Comment: How about @frank [update](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojox/dtl.html#the-update-function)??..

Comment: The DTL is a different implementation. If you are using DTL than you have to create widgets using DTL mixins as shown over here[DTL Widgets](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojox/dtl.html#id7). I am not much familiar with DTL.

Comment: you can also have a look over here for [Templated Widgets](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.7/templated/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can see is that when you're using `dojox/dtl/_Templated` as suggested in the documentation, there is no `update()` function available.

If you really wish for certain things, you will have to manually define a template and render that one (and replace the attach point), for example:

```js
var subtemplate = "<ul data-dojo-attach-point='sysinfo'>{% for item in list %}<li>{{item}}</li>{% endfor %}</ul>";
var template = "<div><h1>{{title}}</h1>" + subtemplate + "</div>";

var CustomList = declare("custom/List", [ _WidgetBase, _Templated, _DomTemplated ], {
    templateString: template,
    subTemplate: new dtl.Template(subtemplate),
    title: "Fruits",
    list: [ 'Apple', 'Banana', 'Lemon' ],
    _setListAttr: function(list) {
        this.list = list;
        this.sysinfo = domConstruct.place(this.subTemplate.render(new dtl.Context(this)), this.sysinfo, "replace");
    },
    _getListAttr: function(list) {
        return this.list;
    }
});
```

Normally, if you would update the template when the list is set, you could use `this.render()` inside the `_setListAttr()` function to update the entire template.

However, as you can see in the `_setListAttr()` function I'm replacing an attach point by a newly rendered Django template.

This results in only that part of the template being updated, in stead of the entire template. So `{{title}}` would remain the original value, even when changed.

A full example can be found on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pb3k3/

Comment: Can you please take a look @ http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojox/dtl.html#the-update-function and http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojox/dtl.html#use-dojo-query

Comment: That function indeed exists on the `dojox/dtl/Template`, but when you're working with widgets, you're inheriting from `dojox/dtl/_Templated` which automates the template rendering and leaves you behind with no references to the actual template. So you have no valid template to work with, since it's integrated in the `dojox/dtl/_Templated` module which you should use when defining widgets with `dojox/dtl`.

Comment: I want a little help from you..Can you join me on chat ? I have created a room for us [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56762/dojo-starters)

Comment: I'm at the chat, however, I have no knowledge of `dojox/dtl`, so if you need help with that, I'm afraid I can't help you much further.